# Passing byte array getting out of bounds error but it passes junit tests

Tags: java, encryption, arrays, bit-manipulation

Working on a little encryption and decryption and the Avalanche effect with des. But while testing it i have run into a bit of a problem with my array being out of bounds. Here is the relevant code im having trouble with:

```
    public static void main(String[] args){

    //take original plain text and get the ct to compare all other ct's to
    String plaintxt = "Coolbro!";
    byte [] ptAr = getBytes(asciiToHex(plaintxt));
    byte [] ctFinal = encrypt(ptAr);
    byte [] ptCopy;
    byte [] newCt;
    int differences =0;

    for ( int j = 63; j >= 0; j--){

        ptCopy = flip(ptAr, 2);
        newCt = encrypt(ptCopy);
        differences = diff(ctFinal,newCt);
        System.out.println(differences);

    }


public static byte [] flip(byte [] a, int position){

    byte[] copy = a;
    String temp = "";
    String tempf = "";
    for(int i = 0; i <= a.length; i++){
        temp = temp + String.format("%8s", Integer.toBinaryString(a[i])).replace(' ', '0');
    }
    if(temp.charAt(position) == '1'){
        for(int i = 0; i < temp.length(); i++){
            if (i == position){
                tempf += "0";
            }
            else{
                tempf += temp.charAt(i);
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        for(int i = 0; i < temp.length(); i++){
            if (i == position){
                tempf += "1";
            }
            else{
                tempf += temp.charAt(i);
            }
        }
    }
    temp = Integer.toHexString(Integer.parseInt(tempf, 2));
    byte [] fin = temp.getBytes();


    return fin;
}
```

flip is just supposed to flip a single bit of the given byte array at the given position ( and It does work, passes the junit tests).

All diff does it tell how many positions are different in the two cipher text arrays. that too works.

But for some reason im havin trouble here

```
ptCopy = flip(ptAr, 2);
```

i know ptAr is a acceptable byte array so i dont see the deal with it throwing errors.These are the errors im getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 8
at AvalancheUtilities.flip(AvalancheUtilities.java:47)
at AvalancheUtilities.main(AvalancheUtilities.java:17)
```

any ideas how to fix that? idk where its coming from

Comment: Which is line `AvalancheUtilities.java:47`?

Comment: ran it again and it should be line 44 instead of 47 but here is 44: `            temp = temp + String.format("%8s", Integer.toBinaryString(a[i])).replace(' ', '0');`

Answer (score 2):

The first `for` loop in your `flip` method needs to be changed, from

```
for(int i = 0; i <= a.length; i++){
```

to

```
for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
```

so you don't run off the end of the array.

Comment: if i do that it fails one of my junit tests. thanks for the reply though

Comment: Then I don't know how your JUnit test succeeds at all with "<=".  As long as the `a` byte array exists, it looks like the `flip` method would _always_ throw `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.